# How to select item in a list from search Result page using Selenium in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

am trying to click on this game to open it's page but every time gives me null pointer exception whatever locator am using still gives me same error also i tried to do a select from list as the link seems to be inside an "li" but didnt work also.

anyone could help me with the code to click this item ??

Targeted Page Url: 
https://staging-kw.games.getmo.com:/game/43321031

```
    Search(testCase);

    WebElement ResultList = driver.findElement(By.xpath(testData.getParam("ResultList")));
    log.info("list located ..");
    List<WebElement> Results = ResultList.findElements(By.tagName(testData.getParam("ResultListItems")));

    for (WebElement List : Results) {
        String Link = List.getAttribute("href");
        try {
            if (Link.equals(null)) {
                log.info("null");
            }

            if (Link.equals(testData.getParam("GameLink")) && !Link.equals("") && !Link.equals(null)) {
                List.click();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException countryIsNull) {
            log.info("LinkIsNull");
        }

    }

    //clickLink(GameLocator,driver);
}`
```

[image]

Comment: Screenshot attached

Comment: Show us the code which you used and got null pointer exception.

Comment: Show your code. Also provide with `URL` of target page (if possible)

Comment: Code and Url updated

Comment: What do you expect with: Link.equals(null) ??? Do you mean Link == null ? Where is the NullPointer in the code?

Comment: I meant that the link value not equal null ..however i get the null pointer exception @ this line  WebElement ResultList = driver.findElement(By.xpath(testData.getParam("ResultList")));

i can't locate the element!

Comment: @KarmaAbdelazeez You should do some debugging, e.g. insert this before the line in which the NPE is thrown: `if (driver == null) log.info("driver is null");
        if (testData == null) log.info("testData is null");
        if (testData.getParam("ResultList") == null) log.info("testData.getParam(ResultList) is null");` This is not about locating but how to set up your test client properly.

Comment: Both the driver and testData Pass but for the "ResultList" param the msg is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this code to work by just adding this line after the search method 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.title")).click();

and how did i get it ? .. i used Selenium IDE to record the actions then converted the code to Java -TestNG to get the exact web element selector